# Image won't load from PHP Script

Tags: php, image

I am updating some images for a script that dynamically creates an image link based on a user's member number. For the old images everything works fine, but for our newly created images the script will not send the right data out.

This link shows the goobledegoop I get with the old images. This is what I need to see. http://cdja.ca/validate_new/img.php?memnum=150&type=2

This link shows that I am not getting the goobledegoop that I need with the new images. http://cdja.ca/validate_new/img.php?memnum=548&type=2

I am outputting the image on this script to prove that the image link is real and valid and loads, but in the finished script this image won't be there. The script should just be passing the goobledegoop out.

Is this some sort of file permission problem, or a problem with my code?

Here is my code.

```
include ("../phpcommon/phpHelper.php");
include ("../quoteadmin/db_writer.php");

$memnum = getParameterString("memnum");
$type = getParameterString("type");

$img = "logo_links/";
$ext = "gif";

/* ----------  Image Versions ----------  */

if ($type == 1){
    // Code for Lifetime Members
    if ($memnum == "001" or $memnum == "002" or $memnum == "006" or $memnum == "015" or $memnum == "121" or $memnum == "153" or $memnum == "323" or $memnum == "150"){
        $filename1 = "Life-White";
        $filename2 = "NotCertified1";
    } 
    else if($memnum == "548" or $memnum == "226"){
        // Code for Vice-Presidents
        // 548 - Jason Cathcart
        // 226 - Mike Di Berardo
        $filename1 = "ViceA";
        $filename2 = "NotCertified-A";  
    }
    else{
        // Code for Other Members   
        $filename1 = "Certified1";
        $filename2 = "NotCertified1";
    }
}

/* -------------------------------------- */

if ($type == 2){
    // Code for Lifetime Members    
    if ($memnum == "001" or $memnum == "002" or $memnum == "006" or $memnum == "015" or $memnum == "121" or $memnum == "153" or $memnum == "323" or $memnum == "150"){
        $filename1 = "Life-Black";
        $filename2 = "NotCertified2";
    }
    else if($memnum == "548" or $memnum == "226"){
        // Code for Vice-Presidents
    $filename1 = "Vice-A";
    $filename2 = "NotCertified-A";  
    }
    else{
        // Code for Other Members   
        $filename1 = "Certified2";
        $filename2 = "NotCertified2";
    }
}

/* -------------------------------------- */

/*

Check Account using Company Name and Membership Number for compliency.
If complient exec Code 1
If not exec Code 2

*/

$companyCount = 0;

$conn = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB);
// check entered parameters against company data
$strsql = sprintf("select count(company_id) from vw_CompliantCompanies where membership_number = %d;", mysql_real_escape_string($memnum));
//echo($strsql . "<br />");
$result = mysql_query($strsql, $conn) or die('Query failed: ' .           mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// if match then
//echo($result."<br>");
if (!(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0))
{
    $companyCount = $row[0]; // only 1 field coming back
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($conn);
if($companyCount == 1)
{
    /* Compliant CODE 1 */
    $logo = "<img src='". $img . $filename1 . "." . $ext . "'><br>" ; 
    echo($logo);
    include $img . $filename1 . "." . $ext; 
}
else
{
    /* Non-Complient CODE 2 */
    $logo = "<img src='". $img . $filename1 . "." . $ext . "'><br>" ; 
    //echo($logo);
    include $img . $filename2 . "." . $ext;
}
```

Comment: I should note that these links both appear to be working in Chrome, however in MS Edge the second link comes up as an HTTP 500 error. I get the same HTTP 500 error with the second link in Chrome when I remove the code to display the image.

Comment: Dug a little deeper and found that my second link is throwing this error -

Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /hsphere/local/home/cdjai/cdja.ca/validate_new/logo_links/Vice-A.gif on line 1 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /hsphere/local/home/cdjai/cdja.ca/validate_new/logo_links/Vice-A.gif on line 1

Google says it's a namespaces issue that would be solved by going to PHP 5.3 or greater. Currently the server is running PHP 5.2